# How can I wrap an If statement around this code?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I was given this project to work on and I'm a bit stumped.  We have a routine being driven by a shortcut macro that will move the Data from Column A to Column F and thus begin to build an itemized list as one works through the column.

What I need, however, is to wrap the current operation in an IF statement so that the operation will not move data to a new cell if the data in G5 (or, RC) is equal to the cell value in A4 (Or, RC-1).  If I can get the logic down, I can get the operation to work as intended.

The Macro was created with a macro recorder, but here is the code:

```
Sub InsertTagLine()

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""TAG: ""&RC[-1]"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need anything more complicated than to just wrap all of your code in an if statement?

```
If (Range("G5").Value <> Range("A4").Value) Then
  'Your code
End If
```

Comment: I believe that is enough to get me going!  I need it to continue the operation in the stages at the bottom, just not the top stages.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, that answer is insufficient.  I need the code to account for vertical scrolling, so a variable is required.